# Computational complexity problem book with solution recommendation?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I will be taking complexity class next quarter and we will use the book "B. Barak, S. Arora, Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach". However, I have little exposure to complexity before and I think the most efficient way to learn anything is to read a bunch of example problems with solutions.

This book has no solution and I wonder if there are books that cover similar topics have solutions to their exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199233217) "The Nature of Computation" (2011) by Christopher Moore and Stephan Mertens also has an accompanying [solutions manual](https://global.oup.com/academic/category/science-and-mathematics/physics/solutions/?cc=nl&lang=en&).